# How to delete pod created with rolling restart?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I ran `kubectl rollout restart deployment`.

It created a new pod which is now stuck in Pending state because there are not enough resources to schedule it.

I can't increase the resources.

How do I delete the new pod?

Comment: have you tried `kubectl delete pod <pod_name>` ?

Comment: The pod can't be deleted with `delete`, new pod is created automatically

Comment: If you create the pod through a deployment or a replica set, simply scale it down to 0

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Scaling it to 0 removes both pods. Then I'll have to scale it back to 1. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

please check if that pod has a Deployment controller (which should be recreating the pod), use:
kubectl get deployments

Then try to delete the Deployment  with
Kubectl delete deployment DEPLOYMENT_NAME

Also, I would suggest to check resources allocation on GKE and its usage on your nodes with next command:
kubectl describe nodes | grep -A10 "Allocated resources"

And if you need more resources, try to activate GKE CA (cluster autoscaler) or in case you already have it enabled, then increase the number of nodes on Max value. You can also try to manually add a new node by manually resizing the Nodepool you are using.

Comment: Doing this will also remove the currently running pod, which will cause downtime